# Applescript - Get information from terminal command

Tags: terminal, network, applescript

I'm creating a little script to allow quick changes to the network settings of my Mac. I have got it all working, but I wanted to be able to see what the settings are before I change them in the first dialog pop up.

The command that gets this information is "networksetup -getinfo *device*"

The result is like this:

```
Manual Configuration --This may also say DHCP Configuration--
IP address: 192.168.0.100
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Router: 192.168.0.1
IPv6: Automatic
IPv6 IP address: none
IPv6 Router: none
Ethernet Address: (null)
```

How can I get the IP address, Subnet mask and Router as 3 variables in my script so I can output them to the user over the following prompts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've whipped up this nice code snippet, try it out, it should work well for your specific application.

```
set device to "Ethernet"

set getInfo to paragraphs of (do shell script "networksetup -getinfo " & device)
set ipAddress to ((item 2 of getInfo) as string)
set subnetMask to ((item 3 of getInfo) as string)
set router to ((item 4 of getInfo) as string)
-- You could use the output here, and remove the rest of the script, or continue to remove the excess wordage.

set ipAddress to ((characters 13 through -1 of ipAddress) as string)
set subnetMask to ((characters 14 through -1 of subnetMask) as string)
set router to ((characters 9 through -1 of router) as string)
```